# I want to create an account for a user in ASP.NET Core identity but I can't insert the data into table dbo.AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a list of users, and I want to select a user and create an account for him. I'm using IdentityUser, but I can't insert data in my table `dbo.AspNetUsers` I will be glad for any help, thanks

This the controller:

```cs
namespace PFE_Management.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        //Injection des dependances 
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signManager;

        public StudentsController(ApplicationDbContext context, 
            UserManager<IdentityUser> user,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = user;
            _signManager = signManager;
        }

        // some code here            
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Student model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _signManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is that you don't have UserName. Although all Microsoft tutorials use email for both user name and email fields - you have to assign both:

```
IdentityUser user = new()
{
    UserName = model.email,
    Email = model.email,
    EmailConfirmed = true
 };
 IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);
```

Also, if you still have an issue - please post the error that you are getting from `CreateAsync()`

Comment: thanks Felix .  I have added that , but I don't have any Problem and I still can't add data to the table .

Comment: That's impossible... either `CreateAsync()` succeeds - and then you have a new record in the table, or it fails - and then you have an exception. Are you sure you are looking in the right database? `IdentityContext` is different from `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: yes I'm sure .  if you have some time you can check my project on github   https://github.com/Iliass-alilou/handShake.git  .  thank you For your Help

Comment: You have to *debug*!!! Your `if (ModelState.IsValid)` fails (LastName and FirstMidName are required fields, and are missing) and therefore Identity code isn't even invoked!

Comment: yes that's true , I have deleted the Required fields , and it's works , thanks a lot MR @Felix